# Use nsIEnvironment to figure out if mouse is left or right handed

Tags: firefox-addon, mouse, xpcom

I want to detect if the user is using their mouse with the left button being primary (e.button == 0) and right as secondary (e.button == 1). Can I do this with `nsIEnvironment`?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIEnvironment

Is it possible to figure out how many buttons the users mouse has with nsIEnvironment?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to do check this at all and actually should not check this at all when working with mouse events.

The [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent.button) state:

> For a mouse configured for left-handed use, the button actions are reversed. In this case, the values are read from right to left.

So you should always assume that `event.button == 0` (left) is primary, `event.button == 2` (right) is secondary, `event.button == 1` is middle click.

If you need this for some other reason: I'm not aware of any way to reliably check this via XPCOM (`nsIEnviroment` has nothing to do with this at all), as this is an underlying functionality of the desktop enviroment/OS that XPCOM does not readily expose. You'd need to write platform-dependent code either using js-ctypes or binary components.

Comment: Well the reason I needed to detect this is because in my button configuration panel I use images. So right now primary button is always showing as left even if the user set it up for right. :(

Comment: I can figure out ctypes with windows (i just use msdn library), but any types on how to figure out ctype on other OS?

Comment: You're in for a lot of pain :p Consult the docs for the OS, which in case of everything *nix is a PITA (X11 vs. MIR vs. Wayland vs...). I have to admit that personally I wouldn't wanna try that.

Comment: Haha aw dang man. Thanks much for those hints though. I think I might revisit this after the addon is done, seems like too much work for something not as important as other unfinished stuff. thx again man!